# Не удается привязать к триггеру событие

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть триггер 'added-to-cart' привязанный к событию добавления корзины. Я хочу привязаться к этому событию с помощью `bind` и добавить свой обработчик, но таким способом как я указал - не получается..

```js
$('.add_to_cart_button').click(function() {
  $('body').bind('added-to-cart', function() {
    $('#shopping-button .cart_list li').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).html());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/?removed_item=1&amp;add-to-cart=3204" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="3204" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Купить</a>

<li id="shopping-button">
  <ul class="cart-dropdown" data-text="was added to the cart">
    <li class="first-dropdown">
      <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
        <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end product list -->
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--/ .cart-dropdown-->
</li>
```

Comment: Как вы триггерите событие? Также непонятно, зачем у вас привязка к событию происходит при клике?
Мне кажется привязка к событию должна быть в $(document).ready(), а при клике только делать .trigger('added-to-cart')

Comment: @LbISS примерно так вешается триггер `a("body").trigger("added_to_cart",[fragments,cart_hash,b]),void 0);`

Comment: не очень понимаю вашего метода - вы мне предлагает переписать все стандартное событие woocommerce?